# django.db.utils.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: first_app_topic.top_name

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm a beginner Django user...

I have this code in my models.py file

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Topic(models.Model):
    top_name = models.CharField(max_length=264, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.top_name

class Webpage(models.Model):
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic, on_delete=models.SET_NULL) # added on_delete parameter, because DJANGO > v2.0 is 
    name = models.CharField(max_length=264, unique=True)
    url = models.URLField(unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class AccessRecord(models.Model):
    name = models.ForeignKey(Webpage, on_delete=models.SET_NULL) # same on_delete needed to be added otherwise t>python manage.py migrate fails
    date = models.DateField()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.date)
```

The above code is updated for Django version > 2.0 (ie with on_delete=models.SET_NULL) included as an argument.

I then run the following commands in the command console

```
python manage.py makemigrations registers the changes to your application.
python manage.py migrate
python manage.py shell
```

```
>>> from first_app.models import Topic
>>> print(Topic.objects.all())
<QuerySet [Topic: Social Network]>
>>> t = Topic(top_name="Social Network")
>>> t.save()
```

This gives the following error log

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\....\MyDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\....\MyDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 396, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
sqlite3.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: first_app_topic.top_name

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\....\MyDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 746, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "C:\....\MyDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 784, in save_base
    force_update, using, update_fields,
  File "C:\....\MyDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 887, in _save_table
    results = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, returning_fields, raw)
  File "C:\....\MyDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 926, in _do_insert
    using=using, raw=raw,
  File "C:\....\MyDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\....\MyDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1204, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(returning_fields)
  File "C:\....\MyDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1392, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\....\MyDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 100, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\....\MyDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 68, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "C:\....\MyDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 77, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "C:\....\MyDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\....\MyDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\....\MyDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\....\MyDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 396, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: first_app_topic.top_name
```

why do i get this error, and what do I need to type / do to fix it, so that it saves ?

This is part of the Udemy course "Python and Django Fullstack Webdeveloper Bootcamp"

If I then add the following to admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from first_app.models import AccessRecord, Topic, Webpage
# Register your models here.
admin.site.register(AccessRecord)
admin.site.register(Topic)
admin.site.register(Webpage)
```

and then run

```
python manage.py createsuperuser
```

I get

```
SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:

ERRORS:
first_app.AccessRecord.name: (fields.E320) Field specifies on_delete=SET_NULL, but cannot be null.
        HINT: Set null=True argument on the field, or change the on_delete rule.
first_app.Webpage.topic: (fields.E320) Field specifies on_delete=SET_NULL, but cannot be null.
        HINT: Set null=True argument on the field, or change the on_delete rule.
```

So I changed
on_delete=models.SET_NULL to on_delete=models.CASCADE

and then reran, and it gave me

Username (leave blank to use 'OneWorld'):

Comment: It means that there is already such `Topic` with that name, and since you specified `unique=True` in the model, the database rejects it.

Comment: how do I rectify ?

Answer (score 0):

as Willem Van Onsem said a topic with that name already exists,I think the best way to rectify this is to access django admin and either go to the topic that has the same name and change its name or simply delete it.